# PyPDF2 append_function can't find file

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

I want to use the PyPDF2 module to merge PDFs.

The following code works fine:

```
import PyPDF2
import sys
import os

input_path = r'\Users\XXXXX\OneDrive\Desktop\PDF_File_Input'

merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
for file in os.listdir(input_path):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        print(file)
```

As soon as I implement the append function I'm getting a traceback error from line 10. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abc.pdf'

```
import PyPDF2
import sys
import os

input_path = r'\Users\XXXXX\OneDrive\Desktop\PDF_File_Input'

merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
for file in os.listdir(input_path):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        merger.append(file)
    merger.write("combined_file.pdf")
```

I don't understand why the file can be found via print but not by the append function.

Comment: Please don't use deprecated classes

Answer (score 1):

If the path is correct, then most likely has something to do with the way you implement the Merger.

```
def run_mergepdf(args):

    check_required(args, ["input", "output"])
    print("Number of input files: {0}".format(len(args.input)))

    #Preliminary checks
    print("Checking read/write status")
    check_files(args.input, action="r")
    check_files([args.output], action="w")

    #Join pdfs
    print("Starting to merge PDFs")
    merger = PdfFileMerger(strict=False)
    for pdf in args.input:
        if os.stat(pdf).st_size != 0:   
            merger.append(PdfFileReader(pdf))
    
    print("Writing merged file: {0}".format(args.output))
    merger.write(args.output)

    print("PDFs merged successfully!")
```

Comment: Please don't use deprecated classes